# How do I put a form in to help mode?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

I am trying to put form into "help mode" in Delphi 2010.

I have a button which the user clicks, and I want the cursor to change to the help cursor, then when a user clicks onto a control, the help for the control is displayed

Is there a window message that I can send?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a form in help-requested mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986790/how-to-place-a-form-in-help-requested-mode)

Comment: @Rob or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392070/how-to-do-context-help-what-is-this-button-in-winforms  Did you find the dupe by searching on the question, or on the answer?

Comment: @David, it was the fourth result for "help mode." Lots of other questions ask *for* help instead of *about* it.

Comment: @RobKennedy Good call. Actually the top hit is enough to answer the question

Comment: Hi I posted this as a seperate question because it related to Winforms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx) message to the form passing `SC_CONTEXTHELP` as `lParam`.

> Changes the cursor to a question mark with a pointer. If the user then clicks a control in the dialog box, the control receives a **WM_HELP** message.

Write something like this in your button `OnClick` event handler:

```
procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CONTEXTHELP, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks David that worked and brought up the help system

Comment: Is there a way of sending a message that would bring up a help popup?

Comment: The context ids on some of my controls are for popup topics in my help system

Comment: Intercept the help command and respond to it differently depending on the context

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to do that David could you show me a little code snippet please?  I have rarely had to get into dealing with API code like this lol

Comment: That would be a new question. I think I answered this one.

Comment: Hi David I have now almost got this working, the only issue I have now is how to set the position of the popup window, I will raise as a new question